# 400 bad request for accessing a "http://Url/_vti_bin/listDate.svc" in sharepoint 2010 web service

Tags: visual-studio-2010, web-services, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, client

I tried to add a service reference to my windows form application in visual studio for accessing :

http://intranet.contoso.com/sites/Lab05/_vti_bin/ListData.svc

but after I click "go" button it returns an error with the following Details :

> There was an error downloading >'http://intranet.contoso.com/sites/Lab05/_vti_bin/ListData.svc'.
>   The request failed with HTTP status 400: Bad Request.
>   Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: >'http://intranet.contoso.com/sites/Lab05/_vti_bin/ListData.svc'.
>   The remote server returned an unexpected response: (400) Bad Request.
>   The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
>   If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution >and adding the service reference again.

but when I enter the address in IE at first time it does not show anything but when I authenticate my self by visiting

http://intranet.contoso.com/sites/Lab05

IE will shows some xml information after entering

http://intranet.contoso.com/sites/Lab05/_vti_bin/ListData.svc

address.

I do these works in windows server 2008 R2 and visual studio 2012 on the same machine which Windows is installed.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is from authentication mode of the web application which i tried to obtain web service from.
anonymous for the web application should be disable.
please refer to this post for changing web application authentication on IIS Manager :

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/22349/listdata-svc-returns-error-400-bad-request-in-visual-studio

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem exactly, In my case (which may be helpful for other)
the problem was that I am using the "DataMemeber" attribute for the enum values like this

```
[DataContract]
public enum Enum1 { 
     [DataMember]
     Enum_Value_Name_1
}
```

this was the cause of the error mentioned above. and the correctness step was

```
[DataContract]
public enum Enum1 { 
     [EnumMember]
     Enum_Value_Name_1
}
```

I discovered this by requesting the Url of the Services in the browser.
all the details of the error was written over there and they was very clean.

**So if you have a similar problem, my advise is : request the WCF Service Url from the Browser and you will get more information about how to solve your (specific) problem.**